# Диалоговое окно выбора изображения с возможностью выбора заданной области

Tags: java, android, android-studio

На главном экране смартфона Android есть возможность выбора изображения с обрезкой под заданную область. Кто-нибудь знает способ реализовать что-то подобное?

Comment: проще всего воспользоваться готовой библиотекой, поискав на том же github.com по запросу "android crop image". Рассказать, как это сделать самому займет слишком много текста и кода.

Comment: спасибо, сейчас попробую